# Smarty foreach not looping through objects in array

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have an array with multiple objects in it that I'm trying to loop through, but the foreach only loops once, like it's only finding the array, but not the objects within.

```
myArray = [
{ name: 1},
{ name: 2},
{ name: 3}
];
{foreach from=myArray item=item key=key}
   console.log("{$key}"); -> prints 0
{/foreach}
```

After it prints 0, it stops running then it should also print 1 and 2 for the indexes.

I've tried nesting foreachs, but when I try that, it errors out. Something like this

```
{foreach from=myArray item=item key=key}
   {foreach from=item item=value key=i}
       console.log("{$i}"); -> error
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Also, when I console.log `myArray[0]`, it prints `{name: 1}` as it should, but the foreach isn't behaving the same way.

Comment: Did you `assign` the array at all? E.g. `$smarty->assign('myArray', $myArray);`